# CodeEffects Rule Editor Keywords support

Tags: codeeffects

Would like to know if the rule editor supports keywords like:
GROUPBY, SUM, AVG, JOIN multiple datatables on Conditions.
Integration with Entity framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing several features in a single question.

If you asking about the Rule-based Data Filtering feature of CodeEffects engine then yes, all that is supported.

In general, CodeEffects supports any LINQ provider as long as it implements a meaning of "where" clause. For example, you can use our Filter extension method in your EF statement to query a table or a view in your database like this:

```
var data = yourIQueryable.Filter(yourRuleXmlString).GroupBy(...).Sum(...).Select(...);
```

Details on Data Filtering in CodeEffects can be found [here](http://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Data-Filtering).

If you need to use any aggregation in your business rules, you can use in-rule methods or rule actions to do that. For example, suppose your source object declares a `List<Country>` collection called Countries and a generic method `Count` that returns the items count:

```
public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }

Method(["Get Count"])
public int Count<T>(List<T> list) { return list.Count; }
```

Having those in your source, you can use CodeEffects to create a rule like this:

```
If Get Count( Countries ) is greater than [2] then ...
```

Details on in-rule methods and actions can be found [here](http://codeeffects.com/Doc), [here](http://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Method-Attribute) and [here](http://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Action-Attribute).